# How can I preserve HTML entities with Diazo?

Tags: xslt, html-entities, diazo

I have the following simple Diazo rules file:

```
<rules
  xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
  xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <theme href="theme/theme.html" />

  <replace css:theme-children="#content" css:content-children=".content" />

</rules>
```

and theme:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The source I want to transform is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
        <a href="&#0109;&#0097;&#0105;lt&#0111;&#0058;info&#0064;example&#46;org">info</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I get is

```
... <a href="mailto:info@example.org">info</a> ...
```

but I want to keep the HTML entities of the href attribute intact. How can I do this with Diazo?

Answer (score 0):

Note numeric character references are not entity references so your title is a bit misleading (the answer for preserving or not entity references such as "& n b s p ; " is very different)

I don't know Diazo but in XSLT if you add

```
 <xsl:output encoding="US-ASCII"/>
```

to your document then any non ascii characters will be output using numeric references.

However in your example they are in fact ascii characters that are quoted such as "." as "." There isn't any standard way in xslt 1 to do that (and there should never be any reason to do that if the document is going to be processed by a conforming html or xml system). Any such system will expand those references to their characters before processing starts. (Which is why XSLT can not preserve them: they have been removed by the xml parser before XSLT sees the input data.)

Comment: If the unicode characters are not ASCII your solution works. unfortunately I need a solution which works for ASCII characters too. &#0109; is the unicode equivialent of ASCII "m"

Comment: All the character references are replaced by the XML parser before the application sees the data. So XSLT has no way of knowing if there were any references in the XML just as it does not know if " or ' are used around attribute values. If you need to make that distinction you need to process the file as plain text not as XML.