# Preserve the &#8198; entity

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I'm transforming an XML-Document to an XML-Document.
The output of this instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="'a&#8198;2'"/>
```

should be:

```
..>a&#8198;2<...
```

The current output is:

```
a 2
```

So the entity is interpreted. How can I escape it?

I tried

1. \
2. /
3. concat('a', ' ', '2')

4.

```
   <xsl:character-map name="entities">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#8198;" string="&#8198;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>


   <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" use-character-maps="entities"/>
```

For the transformation I use *Oxygen 20.1* with embedded *Saxon EE 9.8.0.12*

Comment: I've chosen one particular question as a duplicate of this, but if you search for "XSLT preserve entities" you will find many other similar questions and answers, and I think that between them, they should give you all the information you need.

Comment: That particular answer was different as my problem as I don't handle the entities declared in the stylesheet; I checked it before, also the few others.  Eventually, the solution provided my @imran was a simple one.

Comment: Yes, I should have checked more carefully. Your question isn't actually about entities at all, it is about character references; you're not alone in referring to these incorrectly as entities.

Comment: yes. sorry. Is it possible then to revert the duplication of this question :)

Comment: I've re-opened it. It's actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006514/how-can-i-preserve-html-entities-with-diazo but I'm not allowed to re-close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In Character map you should use
 <xsl:character-map name="entities">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#8198;" string="&amp;#8198;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>
Instead
<xsl:output-character character="&#8198;" string="&#8198;"/>
```